# How does the connection keep refusing?

Tags: python, flutter, rest, dart, python-requests

I'm trying to run some python code into my flutter application. Code is about extracting text from image but when the picture is clicked the connection get refused. I don't know where the problem lies.
Here is code of my flutter page:

```
class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraPage({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  File? _imageFile;
  String? _extractedText;

  Future<void> _captureImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);
        _extractedText = null;
      });

      // Call the RESTful API to extract text from the image
      await _extractTextFromImage();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _extractTextFromImage() async {
    try {
      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST',
        Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/extract_text'),
      );
      request.files
          .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', _imageFile!.path));

      var response = await request.send();
      var responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(responseData);

      setState(() {
        _extractedText = decodedResponse['text'];
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error extracting text: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Camera Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _imageFile != null
                ? Image.file(_imageFile!)
                : const Icon(Icons.camera_alt, size: 100.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _captureImage,
              child: const Text('Capture Image'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            if (_extractedText != null) Text('Extracted Text: $_extractedText'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/extract_text', methods=['POST'])
def extract_text():
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No image file found'})

    image_file = request.files['_imagefile']
    image = Image.open(image_file)

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')  # Replace 'eng' with the appropriate language code

    return jsonify({'text': text})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Whenever i try to run this code there is just the image from the camera and no text. The terminal shows that the connection was refused.

Comment: Is your flask app running on localhost port 5000?  Show us the exact command to run the flask app.

Comment: I use F5 to run my script. Whenever I run my script it shows me following:
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.     
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: